# how to get 2 epoch time value in varibale

Tags: scripts

If I am running this command from command prompt its fine but how to put it in shell script ?
Basically this command is subtracting 2 epoch time but I need their output value in a variable.

```
date -d @$(( $(date -d "`date -d@epochtime2`" +%s) - $(date -d "`date -d@epochtime1`" +%s) )) -u +'%H:%M:%Sa'
```

Thanks

Comment: Can't you put two values in two separate variables and use shell arithmetic expansion to subtract them ? Would make a much more readable code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the output of the command to a variable:

```
diff=$(date -d @$(( $(date -d "`date -d@epochtime2`" +%s) - $(date -d "`date -d@epochtime1`" +%s) )) -u +'%H:%M:%Sa')
echo $diff
```